# Communication between service and application And also to trigger the application with GUI

Tags: c#, service, process, ipc

I have developed an application which does periodical jobs. It runs as windows service in background and manages jobs. I want to trigger another application with GUI from service application when any error notification needs to be given to user. So after seeing err message user will give some response. So now service application (running as service) should do some work based on user response in GUI application (with interface). User response should be communicated to the service application.

So my requirement is

1. Application running as service should be able to trigger another application with GUI (its sufficient if triggering happens only when users are logged in)
2. Communication between an application running as service and application with GUI.

I saw [many links](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/36581/Interaction-between-services-and-applications-at-u) about communication between service and application. Named pipes requires .net 3.5 and above, but I want my application to work in  .net 2 alone. Writing to a txt file and reading it is last option for me as it is not the best method.

So how it can be done? Please give me ideas to start with.

Comment: From your description it does not sound like you GUI app and service need to communicate directly, rather your GUI app needs to be able to write to a config that your service can read and your service needs to write a log your GUI app can read. Both of these can be done by writing to a database or files.

Comment: You've probably already seen this, but just in case: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27210826/cross-process-communication-with-a-windows-service#comment42904848_27210826