# Launching an interactive application that can access network resources from a service

Tags: c#, windows, service, process

I am trying to run an interactive application from a windows service by taking a token from an existing process as shown [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/35773/Subverting-Vista-UAC-in-Both-and-bit-Archite).  This works, but the interactive application is not then able to access network files.  I found that the local system account does not have access to network resources.

How can I launch an interactive application that will be able to access network resources?

Comment: The best approach depends on your needs.  Firstly, why are you launching the application from a service, rather than just running it in the logged on user account?

Comment: @HarryJohnston ok.here is my old question (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27227654/communication-between-service-and-application-and-also-to-trigger-the-applicatio) in which i explained what i am trying to do. Now i am able to run the application, but n/w resources are not accessed from it.

Comment: OK.  I don't recommend using the code you link to in the question; its approach is lousy.  Instead, use WTSQueryUserToken to get a token for the logged on user.  That will give the GUI application the same access to the network as the logged on user has.  (Note that the service will need to run as local system in order to use WTSQueryUserToken.)

Comment: @HarryJohnston ok.Thank u for the information. So can you please give me a example of using WTSQueryUserToken . Also how it is different from the one i mentioned in link?

Comment: I don't have anything to hand.  Try searching for "WTSQueryUserToken" on Stack Overflow and/or your favorite search engine.

Comment: @HarryJohnston By using WTSQueryUserToken i was able to get token of logged on user and able to run GUI application. Please post it answer so that i can mark it as answer. Also can you please give me a sample where service and application communicate using named pipes?(i asked it in my old question, see my old cooments).even using .net 3.5 is ok for me.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb546085%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Answer (score 0):

If the service is running as local system, [WTSQueryUserToken](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa383840%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) is the easiest way to get a token to run code in a given session.  This avoids having to find an existing process to steal a token from, and it ensures that you get a token belonging to the logged-on user (and which therefore has access to network resources).